# Downcasting MyStruct: !Sync + !Send but Arc<Mutex<MyStruct>> is Send + Sync

Tags: rust

I'm using the [downcast_rs](https://docs.rs/downcast-rs/1.2.0/downcast_rs/) crate to do downcast from `Arc<Mutex<dyn MyTrait>>` to `Arc<Mutex<MyConcreteObject>>`

Normally when we have a non `Sync` + `Send` type like `MyStruct`, let's suppose here it's because it holds a pointer `*mut u8`, we actually can think of `Arc<Mutex<MyStruct>>` as being `Sync` + `Send`, and do something like this:

```
struct SafeMyStruct(Arc<Mutex<MyStruct>>);
unsafe impl Send for SafeMyStruct {}
unsafe impl Sync for SafeMyStruct {}
```

so the compiler knows it's safe, because we'll only access those pointers one at a time because they are protected by a `Mutex`.

Is this possible in `downcast_rs`? Here's what I tried:

```
use downcast_rs::{DowncastSync, impl_downcast};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

trait Base: DowncastSync {}
impl_downcast!(sync Base);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    x: *mut u8
}

//Make Arc<Mutex<Foo>>: Send + Sync
struct SafeFoo(Arc<Mutex<Foo>>);
unsafe impl Send for SafeFoo {}
unsafe impl Sync for SafeFoo {}

impl Base for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let mut x = 0;
    let base: Arc<Mutex<dyn Base>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Foo{x: &mut x}));
    let base_ = base.clone();
    std::thread::spawn(move ||{
        base_;
    });

}
```

Error:

```
error[E0277]: `*mut u8` cannot be shared between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:16:6
   |
4  | trait Base: DowncastSync {}
   |             ------------ required by this bound in `Base`
...
16 | impl Base for Foo {}
   |      ^^^^ `*mut u8` cannot be shared between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Foo`, the trait `Sync` is not implemented for `*mut u8`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Foo`

error[E0277]: `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
  --> src/main.rs:16:6
   |
4  | trait Base: DowncastSync {}
   |             ------------ required by this bound in `Base`
...
16 | impl Base for Foo {}
   |      ^^^^ `*mut u8` cannot be sent between threads safely
   |
   = help: within `Foo`, the trait `Send` is not implemented for `*mut u8`
   = note: required because it appears within the type `Foo`

error: aborting due to 2 previous errors; 1 warning emitted
```

Even though `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>` is `Send + Sync`, it looks like it's forcing `Foo` to be `Send` + `Sync`, which would generate undefined behaviour if we implemented.

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: If `Foo` is `!Send`, then `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>` is `!Send`. Adding `unsafe impl Send for SafeFoo` looks like a poor bandaid to the problem. You should instead impl `Send` on `Foo` (and `Sync` if appropriate). I don't know if that fixes the problem with `downcast_rs`, but it'd be more idiomatic nonetheless.

Comment: @kmdreko sorry I didn't mean `!Send + !Sync` I simply meant not `Send` neither `Sync` for example when it has a pointer. How can I make `Arc<Mutex<MyNonSendSyncStruct>>` be `Send + Sync`?

Comment: You need the struct to be `Send`, that's the only way. It doesn't necessarily need `Sync` since `Mutex<T>` is `Sync` if `T` is `Send`.

Comment: *"which would generate undefined behaviour if we implemented"* - if implementing `Send` for `Foo` would yield undefined behavior then slapping it on `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>` won't solve the problem. `Send` is just a marker indicating a type is safe to be moved from one thread to another. So if `Foo` is not safe to be sent to another thread then there's no safe way to make it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** Basically, what you can do to fix your problem at hand is to implement `Send` and `Sync` on `Foo`. But it is important to know whether you *may* do this.

This requirement follows directly from the definition of `downcast_rs::DowncastSync`, which requires all implementing structs (i.e. `Foo`) to be `Send` and `Sync`. Implementing `Send` and `Sync` on any other type such as `SafeFoo` will not help you.

## Send and Sync

It is very important to notice that these traits are **`unsafe`** to implement! This means you should *never* implement them unless you are 100% sure that this is the correct thing to do, otherwise you might cause UB.

In this context, notice, that `Arc` and `Mutex` are *specifically* designed to be used across threads, therefore they have of course already an implementations for `Send` and `Sync` (e.g. `Send` [impl on `Arc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html#impl-Send) and [impl on `Mutex`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Mutex.html#impl-Send)).
However, they have *important* restrictions on their inner type.

Therefore, if you find yourself in a situation where either a `Arc` or `Mutex` is missing a `Send` or `Sync` implementation, it is **never** a problem with either `Arc` or `Mutex`, it is a problem with the inner type!
**Never** implement `Send` or `Sync` yourself an `Arc` or a wrapper around it, it is most definitely UB!

So, the only thing that really matters is whether `Foo` can be considered `Send` and `Sync` and thus whether an implementation of `Send` or `Sync` on `Foo` is sound (i.e. correct). It is of course important that you understand what `Send` and `Sync` are about, so read the docs: [send](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Send.html), [sync](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sync.html).

## Pointers

You should also know, that many types are *automatically* `Send` and `Sync` without you even bothering. There is, however, one important exception to this: pointers!

Pointers are actually *explicitly* defined to be neither `Send` nor `Sync`, and this is despite the fact a pointer per-se can be perfectly `Send` and `Sync`. So if you have a struct that contains a pointer, it *might* be that you can implement `Send` and/or `Sync` on it. But it depends on what you do with that pointer.

The [Rustonomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/send-and-sync.html) has the following to say about pointers and `Send` and `Sync`:

> However raw pointers are, strictly speaking, marked as thread-unsafe as more of a lint. Doing anything useful with a raw pointer requires dereferencing it, which is already unsafe. In that sense, one could argue that it would be "fine" for them to be marked as thread safe.

So, it goes on with:

> However it's important that they aren't thread-safe to prevent types that contain them from being automatically marked as thread-safe. These types have non-trivial untracked ownership, and it's unlikely that their author was necessarily thinking hard about thread safety

## Summary

Whether you can make your code work in a *correct* way depends on what you do with your pointer in `Foo`. If you are confident that you can implement `Send` and `Sync` on it, do it, and your code will work. If not, your code just fundamentally flawed and even if you would get it to compile with some `unsafe` here and there, it would be totally broken! I mean, if you can't share `Foo` between threads, don't do it.

Take for instance your code. You create a pointer into the stack of the main threads. If you ever want to dereference `x`, `Foo` must be neither `Send` nor `Sync`, and it follows that you must never share it or move it between threads.

## Solution

On the other hand, if we assume that we have ownership of the value behind the pointer (similar to a `Box`) then `x` can not be deallocated or anything by another thread, and we can actually move it between threads and still dereference `x`.

Now, having a `Foo` that is at least `Send` is actually sufficient to share it between threads, if it is a `Arc<Mutex<Foo>>`, because the `Mutex` is `Send` **and** `Sync` if `Foo` is at least `Send`. And for the downcast part, we don't really need `DowncastSync` actually, if we just want to pass it around and use it behind a `Mutex`, we can just use `Downcast`.

So, a slightly altered `Foo` can make this work:

```rust
use downcast_rs::{Downcast, impl_downcast};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::any::Any;

trait Base: Downcast {}
impl_downcast!(Base);

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Foo {
    /// A `u8` that is owned by this Foo, like a `Box<u8>`
    x: *mut u8
}
impl Foo {
    pub fn new(inner: Box<u8>) -> Self {
        Foo {
            x: Box::into_raw(inner)
        }
    }
    pub fn access(&self) -> u8 {
        unsafe {
            // This is sound, because we 'own' x so only we have access
            *self.x
        }
    }
}
// `x` is 'owned' (like a Box) so we may move it between threads,
// without fearing that it to gets deallocated
unsafe impl Send for Foo {}

impl Base for Foo {}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(42);
    // Move x into Foo (no references)
    let foo = Foo::new(x);
    // Create a shareable Foo
    // Notice that `base` is Send & Sync
    let base: Arc<Mutex<dyn Base + Send>> = Arc::new(Mutex::new(foo));
    // Move it to an other thread
    std::thread::spawn(move || {
        // Lock mutex
        let guard = base.lock().unwrap();
        // Coerce to a simple trait object, so we can call trait-methods on it
        let my_base: &dyn Base = &*guard;
        if let Some(foo) = my_base.downcast_ref::<Foo>() {
            println!("{:?} = {}", foo, foo.access());
        } else {
            println!("Not a Foo");
        }
    }).join();
}
```